# ZAFClient.init() in not working with NextJs

Tags: next.js, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I am Working on [Zendesk Server Side App](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/build-an-app/building-a-server-side-app/part-1-core-concepts/) next js.

I am trying to **Access framework Api** as mentioned in the Documentation [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/build-an-app/building-a-server-side-app/part-1-core-concepts/#accessing-framework-apis)

```
<script src="https://static.zdassets.com/zendesk_app_framework_sdk/2.0/zaf_sdk.min.js"></script>

var client = ZAFClient.init();
client.invoke('notify', 'Ticket successfully updated!')
```

What I have tried is:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("indexjs use effect")
        getRequester();
      }, []);
    
      const getRequester = async () => {
        console.log("indexjs getRequester")
        var client = ZAFClient.init();
        client.invoke("resize", { width: "100%", height: "600px" });
        const requester = await client.get("ticket");
     }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
    return (
        <div>
          <Script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="https://static.zdassets.com/zendesk_app_framework_sdk/2.0/zaf_sdk.min.js"
          />
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .

       </div>
    );
```

I am getting following error

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ZAFClient is not defined

I am beginner in Front-end framework, If someone has idea of how it can be fix. Help me please.

Thanks!

Comment: Try accessing it with `window.ZAFClient.init()` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves not working `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')`

Comment: Have you tried adding `strategy="beforeInteractive"` to your next/script component? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#strategy

Comment: @Ingirorhaun I tried it too. but not working. What i think is tha ZAFClient can be initialized  only when it is run on zendesk side bar. may i am wrong.